# Check if timestamp is X seconds old in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, timestamp

I have two unix timestamps `old` and `new` and I want to check if 30 seconds has passed between them. I want to check if `oldTs` is 30 seconds old or not. Basically if `oldTs` is `<= 30 second` old then I want to return true otherwise I want to return false.

```
long oldTs = long.Parse(processData.timestamp);
long currentTimestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

return currentTimestamp >= (oldTs + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

I tried above code but I get an error as -

```
Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long' and 'TimeSpan'
```

What is wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Perhaps you are missing a `.TotalMilliseconds` in `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This return a TimeSpan data type.

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
```

You can try get the milliseconds of it.

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).TotalMilliseconds
```

I hope it helps. Happy coding.

Comment: aah got it. Also is my logic right to check 30 second old timestamp?

Comment: @cs98 if what my understanding is correct you want to check if 30 seconds has passed, my thoughts of implementing it is like this:

long oldTs = long.Parse(processData.timestamp);
    var oldDateTime = new DateTime(oldTs);

   return (DateTime.Now - oldDateTime).TotalSeconds == 30;

Answer (score 2):

Set both variables in seconds. You have to simply to `oldTS + 30`.

You can get the the unix timestamp like this

```
long unixTimestamp = (long)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
```